# WebStorm ASP.NET MVC JavaScript Debugging

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, debugging, remote-debugging, webstorm

Does anyone know how to use WebStorm for JavaScript debugging of an ASP.NET MVC application? I am running my ASP.NET MVC application locally using IIS, and I am trying to use WebStorm's remote debugging features to step into JavaScript code. My understanding so far is that you can map local files to the hosted ones, but I'm not sure how to do this since my local files are razor views and don't map 1-to-1 to the HTML that is served via IIS. Any suggestions on how to set this up, or resources on how to do so, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can simply use Chrome's dev-tools instead..

Comment: Does this provide a way to setup javascript unit tests?

Comment: I think you have a better chance of getting your question answered on jetbrains forum than here..

Comment: is using Visual Studios debugger an option?

Comment: Try Remote JavaScript debug configuration, it will load the rendered page from the site where you can place breakpoints. Mapping will not work here.

Comment: I was looking into WebStorm as a possible complement to my development environment especially since it seems to have built in unit testing for javascript, and the intellisense seems to be a little richer. Overall I am pleased with VS and am starting to look into JSTest.NET for my unit testing needs.

Answer (score 5):

I just found your question searching for answers to a different question.

I am running a web application using ASP.NET MVC 5 and several C# libraries supporting it. We use AngularJS and I spend 90% of my time developing in JS on this project. I just downloaded WebStorm 7 as a trial and I created a new project that points to the directory that contains all of my ASP.NET MVC HTML/JS files (it's my entire ASP.NET web project, which excludes my C# libraries, etc.). I am able to set debug breakpoints in WebStorm on my JS files, and it all works well - super easy. This is one option for debugging your ASP.NET app via WebStorm.

The alternative is to use your browser's dev tools, then make changes to your JS files in VS. Otherwise, getting debugging to work in WebStorm was fast and easy.

It has been 1.5 years since you posted this question, so you have moved on I am sure, but for anyone else reading this - hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging JavaScript is the same no matter the backend:

- setup a minified/unminified toggle via a cookie or query param
- check the console for errors in the unminified code
- set up breakpoints to see what is causing the error
- use the browser developer tool to test possible solutions

There are also [remote debugging IIS instructions](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/172351/Remote-Debugging-on-IIS) as well as [cross-domain JavaScript](http://encosia.com/using-cors-to-access-asp-net-services-across-domains/) setup information.

**References**

- [Getting "The data is invalid." error when attempting to run project – JetBrains Rider Support](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000465750-Getting-The-data-is-invalid-error-when-attempting-to-run-project)
- [Using Project Rider under Windows without Visual Studio: prerequisites – JetBrains Rider Support](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207288089-Using-Project-Rider-under-Windows-without-Visual-Studio-prerequisites)
- [WebStorm Help: Configuring Synchronization with a Web Server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-synchronization-with-a-web-server.html)